# filtering datagrids

Tags: datagrid, web, usability, datalist

In a simple scenario there is a webpage with a datagrid containing 2 columns; first name and country. There's a filter set on the grid to filter out all Australians.  There's a form on the same page to add new records and a user decides to add someone from Australia. This record does not meet the filter criteria so would not normally display. However, this might be confusing from the users perspective as they might not have confidence that the person has been successfully added or have forgotten that the filter will mean the new entry is not displayed.

What is the best way to handle this from a usability perspective?:

1. display the new entry but leave the list in a state inconsistent
   with the filter criteria?
2. filter out the new entry but risk confusing the user?
3. provide feedback to the user that the record was successfully
   added but may be filtered out of the list?
4. ?

Answer (score 0):

Three tools I use, Mingle, Jira, and Quicken, use this implementation very effectively; a slight modification to your number 3:

Provide feedback to the user that the record was successfully added, but won't be shown, **and provide a link to the record** using its record identifier (record number + title).